# Why does Teradata SQL Assistant stop color-coding text?

Tags: teradata

I am using a very long .sql file (5,000 lines) in Teradata SQL Assistant. When I initially copy-pasted the text in, I got the usual font-colors (SELECT, FROM, etc show up in blue font, text strings in a pink/purple color, etc.)

However, when I saved and then re-opened this file directly, the font was all black. No colors at all. If I copy-paste the code into a new SQL Assistant query window, the color shows up again. But if I save that new query and then re-open it, I get just a solid black font.

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here? It's not an absolute deal-breaker (I can still run the code), but it's definitely annoying to debug a wall of uniform, black font.

I can't post the code because (1) it's for work and (2) there's a ton of it. It's a long series of INSERT statements into a diagnostic table with the results of running SELECT on a trio of other tables for the purposes of looking for bad data. It does include some long SQL-code snippets as text (within quotes).

Comment: Also: this isn't a bug with my machine. There are several people on my team, and this happens to everyone who uses this file. After saving once, if the file is re-opened, the font is all black. It's annoying all of us, but no one has figured out (1) why it's happening (2) how to stop it.

Comment: This moght be due to the size of the query. There are two options found in `Tools - Options - Query`: *Limit parsing for Queries larger than* and *Limit parsing for Queries larger than* & *Disable parsing for Queries larger than*, try increasing them.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment answered my question, dnoeth. Do you need to submit it as an answer for me to approve it as such?

Comment: Good to know it helped, I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be due to the size of the query, some people complained that parsing/highlighting is too slow for huge source codes.

Now there are two options found in *Tools - Options - Query*:

- *Limit parsing for Queries larger than ... KB*
- *Disable parsing for Queries larger than ... KB*

Try increasing those values.

Comment: Teradata currently does not have those options in the Tools - Options - Query section. I can't copy my queries in color. I will be glad if you can update the solution

Comment: @mert: This is for SQL Assistant, but you probably use Teradata Studio [Express]. Here it's found in *Preferences > Data Management > SQL Development > SQL Editor > Maximum number of lines*

Comment: I use Teradata SQL Assistant 14.01.0.05 version. https://imgur.com/a/zJKUGLc

Comment: SQLA 14 was introduced 2012, why don't you use a recent version?